# How can I sort a list of lists by one of the items in the sublists?

Tags: python

I have a list which looks as follows:

```
list = [[u'schei\xdfunwetter', u'storm', u'0.0007813'], [u'schei\xdfunwetter', u'goddamn', u'0.0002343'], [u'ingenieurin', u'night', u'0.0000442'], [u'ingenieurin', u'you', u'0.0000008'], [u'ingenieurin', u'NULL', u'0.0000004'], [u'ingenieurin', u'last', u'0.0000472'], [u'ingenieurin', u'anything', u'0.0000328']]
```

I'd like to sort this list by the number (=probability).
Looking through previous questions/answers on Stackoverflow, I found the following solution, which seems to have worked for the list (`li = [['a1', 1, 1.56], ['b3', '6', 9.28], ['c2', 1, 6.25]...]`):

```
list.sort(key=itemgetter(2))
```

With my data however, this does not work and returns NONE. 
As I thought that it had to do with the number being a string, I tried the following:

```
sorted_list = list.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[2]))
```

, but this returns another error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.0000723'
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: list.sort *always* returns None. The list is sorted in place.

Comment: It **does** work, **and** returns `None`, *just like it would with any other list*. Don't assign the `None`. "As I thought that it had to do with the number being a string" **Why**? The best way to understand errors is to **read** the error message; and the best way to understand wrong output is to **read the documentation**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [24]: sorted(seq, key=lambda x: float(x[2]))
Out[24]: 
[[u'ingenieurin', u'NULL', u'0.0000004'],
 [u'ingenieurin', u'you', u'0.0000008'],
 [u'ingenieurin', u'anything', u'0.0000328'],
 [u'ingenieurin', u'night', u'0.0000442'],
 [u'ingenieurin', u'last', u'0.0000472'],
 [u'schei\xdfunwetter', u'goddamn', u'0.0002343'],
 [u'schei\xdfunwetter', u'storm', u'0.0007813']]
```

- Use `float` instead of `int`.
- Use the [`sorted` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) instead of the [`sort` method](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists). The sort method
  returns None and modifies the list in place. The `sorted` function returns a sorted copy of the list. If you want to assign
  the result to `sorted_list`, then you need to use the `sorted`
  function.
- Never name a variable `list`, since it shadows the builtin of the
  same name.

Comment: I didn't know that there is a difference in sort and sorted - thanks for pointing that out! It works now... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have to try

```
>>> list.sort(key=lambda x: x[2])
>>> list
[[u'ingenieurin', u'NULL', u'0.0000004'], [u'ingenieurin', u'you', u'0.0000008'], [u'ingenieurin', u'anything', u'0.0000328'], [u'ingenieurin', u'night', u'0.0000442'], [u'ingenieurin', u'last', u'0.0000472'], [u'schei\xdfunwetter', u'goddamn', u'0.0002343'], [u'schei\xdfunwetter', u'storm', u'0.0007813']]
```

`list.sort` will perform operation on self. It will return None. If you have to create new sorted list then you have to use [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) inbuilt function.